# Assigning values of array as variable C#

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I am trying to get the maximum value of a column in a `DataGridView` so I use this line of code:

```
int temp;
var MaxID2 = dataGridView3.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Max(r => int.TryParse(r.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out temp) ? temp : 0);
```

It works fine but only for 1 column and I have 10 columns. I could make it just copy and paste but there has to be a better way. I tried using a `for` loop but I'm stuck on the assigning variables.

Here's what I've got so far; I get error like `Can't convert string to int`:

```
int temp;
//string MaxId;
string[] arr1 = new string[10];
arr1[1] = "MaxID1";
arr1[2] = "MaxID2";
arr1[3] = "MaxID3";
arr1[4] = "MaxID4";
arr1[5] = "MaxID5";
arr1[6] = "MaxID6";
arr1[7] = "MaxID7";
arr1[8] = "MaxID8";
arr1[9] = "MaxID9";
arr1[10] = "MaxID10";

for (int ctr = 1; ctr < 11; ctr++)
{
    var arr1[ctr]= dataGridView3.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Max(r => int.TryParse(r.Cells[ctr].Value.ToString(), out temp) ?
                            temp : 0);

}
```

Comment: The `var` keyword is for instantiating new variables, not assigning to existing ones.

Comment: `new string[10]` -> is accessible via indexes 0 .. 9 (not 1 to 10)

Comment: ok thanks for the reply guys just trying to learn arrays for a while seems like need some more practice..so what would be the best solution for this one?

Comment: You are also trying to store the result of `Max` (which returns an `int`) into an array of type `string`. That explains the error you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `arr1` array is of `string` type while the `Max` function returns an `int`. You should use an array of type `int` or convert the `Max` function result to `string`.

Code with `int` array:

```
int temp;

int[] arr1 = new int[10];

for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
{
    arr1[ctr] = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Max(r => int.TryParse(r.Cells[ctr].Value.ToString(), out temp) ? temp : 0);
}
```

Code with `int` to `string` conversion:

```
int temp;

string[] arr1 = new string[10];

for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
{

    arr1[ctr] = dataGridView3.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                       .Max(r => int.TryParse(r.Cells[ctr].Value.ToString(), out temp) ? temp : 0).ToString();

}
```

Also, pay attention to the `ctr` counter which starts from 0.

See the [Abion47](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255873/abion47) comment to your question about using `var` keyword.

Comment: thanks this one helps and easier to understand..the reason i want to set the ctr =1 because my total columns are 11 but my first column which index is 0 is a Column Fullname thats why i want to separate it from 0 and setting it to ctr = 1..anyway thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to help you @RaymartCalinao.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative without loop and `.Cast`:

```
int[] arr1 = (from c in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
              select Enumerable.Range(0, dataGridView1.RowCount)
              .Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[c, r].Value))).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

"MaxID1" can never be an int because of the "MaxID" part...

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to add a comment to the question... :(

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C# store only values of the type you specify. In your case, you are specifying that your array stores `string` values, but what you actually need is an `int` array. Furthermore, the lengthy preparation you are doing in the array is unnecessary. (It seems like you are trying to "name" each index of the array, which is not how arrays work.)

Here is some code that should do what you are trying to do:

```
int columns = 10;
int[] maxes = new int[columns];

for (int i = 0; i < maxes.Length; i++)
{
    int temp;
    maxes[i] = dataGridView3.Rows
                            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                            .Max(r => int.TryParse(r.Cells[i].Value.ToString(), out temp) 
                                      ? temp 
                                      : int.MinValue);
}
```

First, it declares how many columns you are trying to evaluate and stores it in the `columns` variable. Then it uses that variable in the instantiation of the `maxes` array, since if you know how many columns you are dealing with then that is how big the array needs to be.

In the for loop, the index variable `i` (I use `i` as it's a very common convention for `for` loops) starts at 0, because in C#, the first index of an array is always* 0. From there, it's mostly identical to what you are doing, with the exception that it will default to `int.MinValue` instead of 0 when `int.TryParse` returns false. That is to account for cases where numbers in a column might be negative.

As an alternative, if you are using C# 7.0, you can tweak your `int.TryParse` to use the new form of [out variables](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/):

```
int.TryParse(r.Cells[i].Value.ToString(), out int temp)
```

This removes the need of having to declare `int temp;` before hand. It's a neat little syntactic sugar addition to the latest version of C#.

** There are ways to make non-zero based arrays in C#, but their use cases are extremely limited. Trust me, it's much better to stick with default arrays unless you really know what you're doing.*